# hook into node_admin_content() and alter query

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-hooks

I am working on a custom drupal module and trying to hook into

```
node_admin_content()
```

in order to alter the query which populates the content-type-filter-dropdown on the content administration page?

I want only specified content types to be shown in dropdown. But i dont get it to work.

Anyone has a hint or some snippets for me? Thank you.

Comment: If I understood right, you want to alter a form element.
You could use hook_form_alter().

Comment: Check out this answer.
http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/30633/altering-the-admin-content-form

Hope it helps.